# Routing between same networks

Tags: routing

I have two different sites:

NetA has a subnet 192.168.2.0/24 
NetB has 192.168.1.0/24.

The two sites connect each other via IPsec VPN with fortigate devices. I need to move a server with IP address 192.168.2.240 from NetA to NetB and I cannot change its IP address due to some specific reasons.

My question is; if I move that server from NetA to NetB, is it possible to reach that server from NetA?

Comment: What kind of service is this?  Could you setup a PROXY on original network using the old IP that tunnels/redirects the traffic to a new IP for that system/service on the other site?

Comment: No. No it isn't (unless the networks are bridged as opposed to being routed).

Answer (score 2):

No. Even natting or anything would not work because anything inside NetA wouldn't even ask a router for something presumably in its own network. Is the password related to the IP address?

Answer (score 2):

The network portion of the IP address defines what network the host is on.  You cannot put a host on a different subnet without changing its IP address.

You could certainly create a new subnet for that device at the other site, but then all the hosts at the site it was at before would assume it was on their local subnet (the new subnet could not be made routeable to them with that prefix), and couldn't get to it.

So, no, you have to renumber it in this case.  It may be a multi-step change, but it's necessary in this case.

Comment: "You cannot put a host on a different subnet without changing its IP address" - Well you could... but it wouldn't work. ;)

Comment: It wouldn't be on a different subnet, technically, though this can be muddled.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not clear enough; it will probably not work out of the box because your router will route that subnet to a tun/tap device and not to your local lan.

If you just want to reach it for changing the ip address you could install a second host in the same subnet temporarily.